# android xmlPullParser unterminated entity ref

Tags: android, xml

I keep getting this error and i don't know how to solve it or what it evens mean? can anyone help me?

Logcat:

```
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @13:51 in java.io.BufferedReader@42ac6658) 
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEntity(KXmlParser.java:1210)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1392)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at com.flamand.parksniffer.eventhandling.XmlParser.getStackSitesFromFile(XmlParser.java:115)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at com.flamand.parksniffer.fragments.EventsEventFragment$SitesDownloadTask.onPostExecute(EventsEventFragment.java:102)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at com.flamand.parksniffer.fragments.EventsEventFragment$SitesDownloadTask.onPostExecute(EventsEventFragment.java:1)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-07 21:57:55.801: W/System.err(9369):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The parser class:

```
package com.flamand.parksniffer.eventhandling;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;


public class XmlParser{

    static final String KEY_EVENTS="events";
    static final String KEY_EVENT="event";
    static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    static final String KEY_DATE="date";
    static final String KEY_INFO="info";
    static final String KEY_IMG="img";

    public static List<Event> getStackSitesFromFile(Context ctx) {

        // List of StackSites that we will return
        List<Event> events;
        events = new ArrayList<Event>();

        // temp holder for current StackSite while parsing
        Event curEvent = null;
        // temp holder for current text value while parsing
        String curText = "";

        try {
            // Get our factory and PullParser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("events.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            // point the parser to our file.
            xpp.setInput(reader);

            // get initial eventType
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                // Get the current tag
                String tagname = xpp.getName();
                // React to different event types appropriately
                /**switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_EVENT)) {
                        Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing started 9");
                        // If we are starting a new <event> block we need
                        //a new StackSite object to represent it
                        curEvent = new Event();
                        Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing started 6");
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing started 3");
                    //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    Log.d("Parksniffer", curText);
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing started 4");
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_EVENT)) {
                        events.add(curEvent);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_INFO)) {
                        Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing info");
                        curEvent.setInfo(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME)) {
                        curEvent.setName(curText);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }*/
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                    // If we are starting a new <event> block we need
                    //a new StackSite object to represent it
                    if(tagname.equals(KEY_EVENT)){
                        Log.d("Parksniffer", "699");
                        curEvent = new Event();
                    }
                }
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
                    Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing started 3");
                    //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    Log.d("Parksniffer", curText);  
                }
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
                    Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing started 4");
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("/"+KEY_EVENT)) {
                        events.add(curEvent);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("/"+KEY_INFO)) {
                        Log.d("Parksiffer", "Parsing info");
                        curEvent.setInfo(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("/"+KEY_NAME)) {
                        curEvent.setName(curText);
                    }
                }
                //move on to next iteration
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the populated list.
        return events;
    }

}
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
        <event>
            <name>Sinterklaas Parade</name>
            <info>Een zeer aangename stoet rond de stad Roeselare waar Sinterklaas de kinderen zal begroeten</info>
            <img></img>
        </event>
        <event>
            <name>Carnaval</name>
            <info>Een evenement dat je zeker niet mag missen! Vier carnaval in Roeselare!</info>
            <img></img>
        </event>
</events>
```

If there is anything more you need, i will post it. And can you please explain me a bit why it's giving me this error while my xml file (as far as i know) is bug free? because all the other places i see this is because of xml bugs and yeah... anyway thanks for reading

Comment: An entity ref is something beginning with `&` and terminated with `;` - the locator says its row 13 column 51 but the document you posted doesn't seem to have anything there.

Comment: that's what i thought, so what it is the error then?